# jQUery Mobile Navigation Correction

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, navigation

Thank you for taking a look at my question and thank you for your help.

I have a responsive website that I'm creating a mobile navigation for (from 760px). It works great and looks great, but I'm having a problem with submenu.

Now, I'm not very good with jQuery and as such you might find my work to be a bit messy, I apologies in advance and appreciate any help to make it look cleaner and less.

What I need:
 1. I want the the submenus to display independently. What I mean is:
   (i) On Google Chrome: if I click on "Products" (which has submenus), "Clients" (which also has sub menus) also expands and vice versa. I want them to be independent of each other.
  (ii) On Moxilla FireFox: Clicking "Product" (which has submenus) will also expand the "Clients" but not vice versa. Again, I want them and other sub menus I will have to be independent of each other.

2. Just like jQuery accordion, is it possible to have an active menu (with submenu) retracts once another menu (with submenu) is clicked? I really want this as well. What I mean is, if "Products" (which has sub menu) is currently active, when clicking "Clients" (which also has submenus), the Products should retracts as the clients expands and so on...
3. I'm building this for people who might have varying needs for submenus, therefore more or less submenus will be created. Once created, I want the submenus to pickup and assume the predefined functions without the need to do extra coding or make additions on the jquery for more submenus. People that will be using this have no jQuery knowledge. I want them to just focus on customizing the html and css of the menu while the jQuery is already done for them.
4. If you can make jquery less bucky, I mean, compress it or something, that will be great.

NOTE: If you are viewing the jsfiddle example below on full screen, please resize your browser window to 760px to see the navigation.

Here's a jsfiddle link to the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/Delinx/8tstrfuq/

```
$(function() {
        var bar         = $('#bar');
            menu        = $('#mobile-navigation ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(bar).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 480 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });

$(function() {
        var submenu         = $('#mobile-submenu li');
            submenuHeight   = submenu.height();

        $(sub).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            submenu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 480 && submenu.is(':hidden')) {
                submenu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
```

Thank you very much, I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: You are using non-unique IDs e.g. #mobile-submenu in the HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Try using classes instead and then only toggling items under the clicked parent, e.g.: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8tstrfuq/1/

Comment: Hi Omar,
10000 thank yous, it looks great and works great. But have you noticed that the sub navigation are displayed upon load? I want them to be displayed only when the parent menu (menu with the sub) is clicked. If you click on the menu bar now you will see that as the bar drops down and reveals the menu, the parent menu also drops down and shows the submenus.

Is it possible to only show the submenus upon clicked?

Again, thanks a bunch for a great help.

Comment: I am not Omar, but yes, change the line menu = $('#mobile-navigation > ul'); The > makes it only toggle the immediate child of bar. Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8tstrfuq/2/

Comment: @ezanker a little more help, please. Everything looks great but if you click on any of the submenus, it doesn't go to their prospective pages (links), instead it retracts the sub navigation. Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/Delinx/6fhho26h/. All the submenus are linked to google.com but upon clicked, instead of going to google.com, it acts as the parent menu and retracts it.

I really need help on this. Contributions from anyone is most welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the $('sub') selector to handle click on the actual link not the whole li, then change how you find the submenu accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6fhho26h/2/